# Updating Android Studio code templates

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio has couple of code templates. For example there are activity template for `LoginActivty` through which you can generate a Login Activity with inbuilt `GooglePlus` sign in options.

But this template is obsolete as it uses old `GooglePlus` api object rather than latest `GoogleApiClient` however this can be updated manually I was looking are there updated templates available?

And if I have to update my templates what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are there updated templates available?

At the moment, templates are updated only as part of an Android Studio update. So, if you are on the current Android Studio, you are on the current templates.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating your own template, if there are no updates from Google.
http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/215-mobile/6843-custom-projects-in-android-studio.html

I guess you will need to create your customised template.